# How to 'time-zone-proof' a sharepoint list/forms library. Tuesday off in New York should be Tuesday off in LA

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

Office365 Enterprise site with an infopath form for time off.
I have users in all US Time Zones. I am in New York, Eastern Time

MY users in LA say when they enter 2/1/2017 as the first day off, the list view shows 1/31/2017.  This is technically true, I suppose, in that 2/1/17 00:00 New York time is exactly 1/31/17 9:00PM, it is misleading.

If I store the date as text, yyyy-mm-dd, it doesn't get converted, and is sortable. But is this really my only option?

Answer (score 0):

The data in the form is interpreted by a human for entry into a payroll system, so leaving it in UTC Time (and the 'wrong day' in LA) doesn't have any ramifications.

So I'm going to use **Moment.js** to express all dates onscreen in New York time regardless of the user's local settings. This will produce a uniform (and correct) day worldwide.

Comment: This won't help me in LIST VIEWS. :(